# POST /hub/security/csp-report ‘_xsrf’ argument missing from POST in jupyterhub

Tags: embed, jupyterhub

I want to embed jupyterhub into my angular project for that I have write some code in jupyterhub_config.py file that i attached below.After doing that, I am able to login to jupyterhub in my angular project but after starting server i am facing error of 403. Api of csp-report is failed.Please help me to find solution for it
Thank you
error:
403 POST /hub/security/csp-report (192.168.1.9): ‘_xsrf’ argument missing from POST
403 POST /hub/security/csp-report (@192.168.1.9) 9.71ms

[image]